# Product rule in limit

Tags: calculus

I have [looked on Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x%20to%200%20%28lnx%29%2F%28x%29) for the limit of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln x}{x}$

The full answer uses one-sided limits, and the product rule stating that for $0^{-}$ is a product of $-\infty \cdot -\infty=\infty$ and for $0^{+}$ is a product of $-\infty \cdot \infty=-\infty$

does the product rule stands for a finite limit and not infinity? why does $-\infty \cdot -\infty=\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

The product as a continuous mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ can be extended in exactly one way to a continuous mapping $(\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\})^2\to\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ (with the obvious compact topology) except at the points where $0$ is multiplied on the left or on the right by one of the infinities. There is no ambiguity about multiplying infinities by infinities.

Answer (score 0):

For $x \to 0^-$ the expression is not well defined, then we need to restrict to the case $x\to 0^+$.

From here, by the definition of limit is easy to see that

$$f(x) \to \infty \;\; g(x) \to \infty \implies f(x)g(x)\to \infty$$

$$f(x) \to \infty \;\; g(x) \to -\infty \implies f(x)g(x)\to -\infty$$

$$f(x) \to -\infty \;\; g(x) \to -\infty \implies f(x)g(x)\to \infty$$